# Getting Error when making calls to API gateway cross account

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I created a API Gateway resource policy in my account to give another AWS account to make the API calls:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::92121395014:root"
            },
            "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:us-west-2:86219495289:74lbi0nlsf/*/*/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now, when I try to make calls from a lambda in.AWS account 92121395014 to API gateway in 86219495289 AWS account, then it is throwing error with 403. Why is to so? When I create a IAM user in account  92121395014 and use that to make calls from postman using AWS key and secret, then it works fine. Any idea why and how can I fix it?

Comment: To clear my understanding, are you calling API gateway in Account B which is connected to Lambda in account B from a Lambda in account A by an HTTP call?

Comment: Or, are you calling an API Gateway from account B which is connected to Lambda in account A?

Comment: can you please provide the IAM permissions for the user and lambda role in the 92121395014 account?  the resources in the 92121395014 need IAM permissions to invoke your API as well, maybe the user has them but your lambda role does not

Comment: @kkesley Lambda in Account B is calling API gateway in Account A.

Comment: @JDD I gave the lambda execution role administrative access also. Even then, it didn't work for me.

Comment: Can that anything be do with root user? What does it mean?

Comment: @hatellla using HTTP library? AWS SDK? what if you use the same IAM credentials that you used in PostMan in the lambda? will it still give 403?

Comment: Yeah when I use IAM credentials in lambda, then it works fine. But not with IAM role.

Comment: Any idea why it is not working with Role?

Comment: what do you mean you tried using IAM credentials in lambda and it works?  It is not possible for a Lambda to use an IAM user as they are not assumable.  Can you confirm that the lambda role has Invoke permissions for API GWs in external accounts?  Also, I assume you are using IAM authentication and signing the requests?

Comment: Has anyone found a solution for this? I'm trying to allow a Lambda in Account B to call an API Gateway in Account A..I have an execution role set up on the Lambda in Account B, and the resource policy on the API Gateway in Account A allows the IAM role to invoke the APIs..but it still throws a 403..I think it has to do with the Lambda using an STS asssumed Role, while the API Gateway policy only references the "regular" (non assumed) Role IAM for the execution role... I'm honestly stunned that there is no AWS documentation around this (allowing a Lambda to invoke an APIGW cross-account)